# List that repeats based of numbers in original list

Tags: python, list

From this list:

```
list=[3,4,1]
```

How do you get this list?:

```
desired_list=[3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1]
```

My attempt:

```
count=0
if count<list[count]:
    print(list[count])
    count+=1
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `lst` then for `range(element)` repeat that element.

Try this:

```
>>> lst=[3,4,1]
>>> [l for l in lst for _ in range(l)]
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read up on the basics of python (or any other language), e.g. [for-loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and go from there.

Right now your code only executed `count+=1` once.